# How to include normalize.scss in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, normalize

Create a `vue` project and I want to be able to use `normalize.scss` in this, in the console I installed it in the following way

```
npm install normalize.scss
```

This I install the dependency on my `package.json` file, but now I do not know how to use normalize globally in my project.

Where do I call the normalize and where do I put it so that I can take it in all the pages of my project?

Comment: Are you using webpack?  Did you create your project using vue-cli?  Do you have SASS setup in your project?

Comment: @zero298 Yes, create my project with vue-cli and also configure it with sass

Comment: @EdwinAquino What is your command for running the dev server? Aka the command you see in `package.json`? Does it have something with `vue-cli-server` or `./build/whatever`?

Answer (score -1):

I found clearly [how to use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-scss).

This mean than you have to import it in your sass file using:

```
@import 'normalize-scss';
@include normalize();
```

After this your sass file is imported inside your main.js i guess.

Comment: We don't even know if the OP is using webpack which is a prerequesite to using loaders like this.

Comment: `[vite] Internal server error: Failed to find 'normalize-scss'`... and btw, the page mentions vue 0 times :)